# symfony2 warning: sqlite3 profiler database is readonly

Tags: ubuntu, sqlite, symfony

I'm getting a strange warning I can't fix with Symfony2 version v2.0.12. This was working fine yesterday. The only relevant recent change I suspect is my recent upgrade of symfony2 itself (installed into `vendors/symfony`) from v2.0.5 to v2.0.12.

```
Warning: SQLite3Stmt::execute(): Unable to execute statement: attempt to write a readonly database in /Symfony2/vendor/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Profiler/SqliteProfilerStorage.php on line 66

Call Stack:
    0.0000     329108   1. {main}() /Symfony2/web/app_dev.php:0
    0.0015     720736   2. Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->handle() /Symfony2/web/app_dev.php:10
    0.0102    1461700   3. Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\HttpKernel->handle() /Symfony2/vendor/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Kernel.php:171
    0.0102    1462608   4. Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle() /Symfony2/vendor/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/HttpKernel.php:47
    0.0102    1462608   5. Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleRaw() /Symfony2/vendor/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/HttpKernel.php:71
    0.0594    4226612   6. Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->filterResponse() /Symfony2/vendor/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/HttpKernel.php:139
    0.0595    4232664   7. Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\ContainerAwareEventDispatcher->dispatch() /Symfony2/vendor/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/HttpKernel.php:157
    0.0598    4245456   8. Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher->dispatch() /Symfony2/vendor/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/ContainerAwareEventDispatcher.php:145
    0.0599    4246116   9. Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Debug\TraceableEventDispatcher->doDispatch() /Symfony2/vendor/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/EventDispatcher/EventDispatcher.php:49
    0.0609    4265376  10. call_user_func() /Symfony2/vendor/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Debug/TraceableEventDispatcher.php:82
    0.0609    4265404  11. Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ProfilerListener->onKernelResponse() /Symfony2/vendor/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Debug/TraceableEventDispatcher.php:0
    0.0640    4470124  12. Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Profiler\Profiler->saveProfile() /Symfony2/vendor/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/EventListener/ProfilerListener.php:124
    0.0640    4470124  13. Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Profiler\PdoProfilerStorage->write() /Symfony2/vendor/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Profiler/Profiler.php:91
    0.0650    4516660  14. Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Profiler\SqliteProfilerStorage->exec() /Symfony2/vendor/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Profiler/PdoProfilerStorage.php:103
    0.0651    4563392  15. SQLite3Stmt->execute() /Symfony2/vendor/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Profiler/SqliteProfilerStorage.php:66
```

In `app/logs/test.log` I see lines like

```
[2012-03-30 14:40:49] profiler.WARNING: Unable to store the profiler information. [] []
```

Any ideas?

I stepped through SqliteProfilerStorage in a debugger and learned that the Sqlite3 database in question is at `app/cache/dev/profiler.db`.

```
$ ls -l app/cache/dev/profiler.db
-rw-r--r--+ 1 adam www-data  51200 2012-03-30 13:56 app/cache/dev/profiler.db

$ getfacl app/cache/test/profiler.db
# file: app/cache/test/profiler.db
# owner: www-data
# group: www-data
user::rw-
user:www-data:rwx       #effective:r--
user:adam:rwx           #effective:r--
group::rwx          #effective:r--
mask::r--
other::r--
```

I regularly run phpunit tests from the command line and also hit an Apache2 VirtualHost pointed at the same Symfony2 application. I thought ACLs would allow these two to happen interchangeably, but I'm a bit confused by `effective:r--` in the ACLs, above.

I set up permissions [according to the install doc](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/installation.html). I did this:

```
$ mkdir app/{cache,logs}
$ chmod 775 app/{cache,logs}
$ sudo setfacl -R -m u:www-data:rwx -m u:`whoami`:rwx app/cache app/logs
$ sudo setfacl -dR -m u:www-data:rwx -m u:`whoami`:rwx app/cache app/logs
```

And again, this just started causing issues, so I'm suspecting the Symfony2 upgrade. I'm looking through the commits though, and I haven't found anything yet that might have recently broken this.

- `umask` for both my user (`adam`) and `www-data` returns `0002`.
- I'm using Ubuntu 11.10.
- [This thread covers a similar symptom](http://forum.symfony-project.org/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=35324), but the suggested resolution doesn't work for me. `profiler.db` always has permissions `0644`.

Comment: I have the same issue, but just want to point out that I got it on 2.0.9 as well as 2.0.12

Comment: There shouldn't be a need for `chmod` if you're using acl lists. I suppose you've already tried removing the contents of `cache` and letting Symfony rebuild it from scratch?

Comment: @gilden yes, tried that. It's strange... almost as if the ACLs aren't working. `getfacl` seems to be working, though. The fs is ext4.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

maybe it's only because you forgot to **recursively** set the 775 permissions on the files.

Try with

```
chmod 775 -R app/{cache,logs}
```

Comment: Hmm, I'd have to do that often, then. Up until I started seeing this issue, I've been regularly running `rm -rf app/{cache,logs}/*` when things get mucked up.

Comment: It's been a while, but I'm pretty sure that was the problem. The cause was probably something in the Symfony2 framework creating the sqlite db with incorrect permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the parent directories permissions ?

I solved a similar issue with this:

```
chgrp www-data app app/symfony.db
chmod 775 app
chmod 664 app/symfony.db
```